# UICollectionView not calling didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a Collection View and has custom cells with images and labels in there. I have set my collection view as follows -

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 150.0f;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 104.0f;
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 100, 120);

_archiveCollectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
_archiveCollectionView.frame = CGRectMake(30, 218, _archiveCollectionView.frame.size.width - 60, _archiveCollectionView.frame.size.height - 350);
_archiveCollectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
_archiveCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
_archiveCollectionView.delegate = self;
_archiveCollectionView.dataSource = self;
[self.archiveCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FullArchiveEditionCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

[_archiveCollectionView reloadData];
[self.view addSubview:_archiveCollectionView];
```

I have also set the following methods:

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return _chosenCategoryArray.count;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [self addEditionsChildView];
}
-(BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
```

However, my `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` never gets called when I select a cell. Any help please?

Comment: Did you try putting NSLog or breakpoint inside the method?

Comment: Yes - and it doesn't call it

Comment: any of datasource method get called ? place break point on each method & check it.

Comment: in the identity inspector of FullArchiveEditionCell.xib, The file owner's class should be NSObject and the view's class should be FullArchiveEditionCell.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and it turned out I was using the same cell reuse identifier in two different collection views

Comment: Wow how subtle. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

In your header file have you implemented `UICollectionViewDelegate` as like below,

```
@interface HAViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Yes I have included that

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. And I solved by using storyboard to locate the **collection cell** in the collection view controller. Then tick **User InterAction Enabled**. I think using code to set in the UICollectionViewCell would also work. Hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Try with changing sequence as given below

```
[_archiveCollectionView reloadData];
[self.view addSubview:_archiveCollectionView];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:_archiveCollectionView];
[_archiveCollectionView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the below delegate method.

```
- (BOOL)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView shouldDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return YES;
}
```

And implement your

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //your selection management code 
}
```

and

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //deselection handling code 
}
```